# How to append dictionary to a json file one by one?

Tags: python, json

I have following code which generates one json object in every iteration. I want to append such objects in a new line in json file with every iteration and not by making a list of dictionaries and then converting it into a json.

```
def generateDicts(log_fh):
    m = 1
    currentDict = {}
    for line in log_fh:
        if line.startswith(matchDate(line)):
            if currentDict:
                yield currentDict
            try:
                regexp = re.match(r'(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ)\s+(INFO|WARN|DEBUG|ERROR|FATAL|TRACE)\s+(.*?\s+.*?)(.*?\-\s+.*?)\s+(?:(\[?.*?\])?)(.*)', line)
                currentDict = {
                               "@timestamp" : regexp.group(1),
                               "Severity" : regexp.group(2),
                               "Thread" : regexp.group(3),
                               "Class" : regexp.group(4),
                               "Component" : regexp.group(5),
                               "Message" : regexp.group(6),
                               "id's" : re.findall(r'\b[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b', regexp.group(6))
                              }
            except:
                m = m + 1
                print(m)
                print(line)
        else:
            currentDict["Message"] += line
    yield currentDict
```

File created-

```
[
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z",
      "Severity":"INFO",
      "Thread":"ActivityEventRecovery-1 ",
      "Class":"ActivityCacheManager -
    -",
      "Component":"[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]",
      "Message":" Handling activity
    c85ce68a-1729-4f06-8eb9-4dadd1a59f76 completion event for 1",
      "id's":[
         "c85ce68a-1729-4f06-8eb9-4dadd1a59f76"
      ]
   },
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:25:00.123Z",
      "Severity":"WARN",
      "Thread":"http-nio-127.0.0.1-7440-exec-127 ",
      "Class":"CorfuCompileProxy -
    accessInner:",
      "Component":null,
      "Message":"Encountered a trim
    exception while accessing version 120383907 on attempt 0",
      "id's":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:23:08.700Z",
      "Severity":"INFO",
      "Thread":"RpcManagerRequestCleanupTimer ",
      "Class":"RpcManager -
    SYSTEM",
      "Component":"[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\"
    subcomp=\"manager\"]",
      "Message":" Rpc response not received for
    application FabricStats request
    com.vmware.nsx.management.agg.messaging.AggService$ClientDataRequestMsg
    from client 8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a with correlation id
    287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068 in 432000000 msec.",
      "id's":[
         "8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a",
         "287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068"
      ]
   },
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:24:04.072Z",
      "Severity":"INFO",
      "Thread":"MessagingObjectFactoryImpl-4-2 ",
      "Class":"ExporterLastAckServiceImpl - -",
      "Component":"[nsx@6876
    comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]",
      "Message":" Found exporter with elaId =
    Node#a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6#AggSvc-L2-Bridging,
    returning lastAck = 16507 ",
      "id's":[
         "a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6"
      ]
   },
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z",
      "Severity":"INFO",
      "Thread":"ActivityEventRecovery-1 ",
      "Class":"ActivityCacheManager - -",
      "Component":"[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\"
    subcomp=\"manager\"]",
      "Message":" Handling activity
    92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1 ",
      "id's":[
         "92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0"
      ]
   },
   {
      "@timestamp":"2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z",
      "Severity":"DEBUG",
      "Thread":"ActivityEventRecovery-1 ",
      "Class":"ActivityCacheManager - -",
      "Component":"[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\"
    subcomp=\"manager\"]",
      "Message":" Handling activity
    92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1\n",
      "id's":[
         "92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0"
      ]
   }
]
```

File I want -

````
{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:25:00.123Z", "Severity": "WARN", "Thread": "http-nio-127.0.0.1-7440-exec-127 ", "Class": "CorfuCompileProxy - accessInner:", "Component": null, "Message": "Encountered a trim exception while accessing version 120383907 on attempt 0", "id's": []}
{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:23:08.700Z", "Severity": "INFO", "Thread": "RpcManagerRequestCleanupTimer ", "Class": "RpcManager - SYSTEM", "Component": "[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]", "Message": " Rpc response not received for application FabricStats request com.vmware.nsx.management.agg.messaging.AggService$ClientDataRequestMsg from client 8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a with correlation id 287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068 in 432000000 msec.", "id's": ["8ac94189-d611-4eb3-9b93-c3c3a8e3d36a", "287e690e-0a47-4459-a0bb-be36fe439068"]} 
{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:24:04.072Z", "Severity": "INFO", "Thread": "MessagingObjectFactoryImpl-4-2 ", "Class": "ExporterLastAckServiceImpl - -", "Component": "[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]", "Message": " Found exporter with elaId = Node#a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6#AggSvc-L2-Bridging, returning lastAck = 16507 ", "id's": ["a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6"]}
{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z", "Severity": "INFO", "Thread": "ActivityEventRecovery-1 ", "Class": "ActivityCacheManager - -", "Component": "[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]", "Message": " Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1 ", "id's": ["92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0"]}
{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z", "Severity": "DEBUG", "Thread": "ActivityEventRecovery-1 ", "Class": "ActivityCacheManager - -", "Component": "[nsx@6876 comp=\"nsx-manager\" level=\"INFO\" subcomp=\"manager\"]", "Message": " Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1\n", "id's": ["92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0"]}```
````

Comment: provide some sample data that is generated from this function and how the final JSON file should look like

Comment: Just edited, kindly look

Comment: Paste the function which is actually creating the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

with open(FileName, "a") as outjs:

    c=[{"@timestamp": "2019-11-14T04:25:00.123Z", "Severity": "WARN"},{ "Thread": "http-nio-127.0.0.1-7440-exec-127 ", "Class": "CorfuCompileProxy - accessInner:", "Component": None, "Message": "Encountered a trim exception while accessing version 120383907 on attempt 0", "id's": []}
   ]
    for currentDict in c:
        json.dump(currentDict, outjs)   # write the dictionary
        outjs.write('\n')
```